# How to config tsconfig.json to get this output?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this repo:

```
.
|- app1
|  |- src
|  |  |- index.ts
|  |- tsconfig.json
|  |- package.json
|  |- dist
|- shared
|  |- libs
|  |  |- lib1.ts
|  |  |- lib2.ts
```

Shared libs are utils shared across different apps.

When I compile app1 (with tsc) I would like to get this in the dist folder:

```
.
|- app1
|  |- src
|  |  |- index.ts
|  |- tsconfig.json
|  |- package.json
|  |- dist
|  |  |- index.js
|  |  |- libs
|  |  |  |- lib1.js
|  |  |  |- lib2.js
```

But I cannot manage to make it work... Any help?

(I have already tried with rootDirs and paths config)

Comment: You mean  you want your compiled JS files in the `dist` folder. But would also like, the compiled files from the shared folder, outside your root directory, to be in the dist folder?

Comment: I would suggest you publish your package to either 
1. your own NPM repository (example Verdaccio) 
2. NPM 
3. or npm install the shared folder over git+ssh

And then use the shared folder as a normal module.